# Array function for sum of number, starting with an alphabet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of numbers in column H10:H26 and I need an array function to find the SUM of numbers followed by "G" and "I".

The numbers vary from a single digit to 4 digits

```
{=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(H10:H26,3)))}
```

Well this did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBSTITUTE(H10:H26,LEFT(H10:H26,2),"")))
```

To sum up just the G- you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(H10:H26,2)="G-")*(SUBSTITUTE(H10:H26,LEFT(H10:H26,2),"")))
```

And to sum up just the I- update the formula by substituting out the G:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(H10:H26,2)="I-")*(SUBSTITUTE(H10:H26,LEFT(H10:H26,2),"")))
```

Comment: What if i wanted the sum sepratly , if I only need Sum Of number starting with "G"

Comment: Do you mean sum up all of the G- in one cell and all of the I- in another cell? Also, which do you prefer, keeping the minus sign or extracting it?

Comment: Yes Exactly G and I Separately, No I don't need the '-' actually those are 'hyphens'